# Set window transparency in terminal in Mint

Tags: linux-mint, transparency, cinnamon

I use [urxvt](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/rxvt-unicode.html) on [Mint 13 Cinnamon](http://blog.linuxmint.com/?p=2031) and I'd like it to be partially transparent.

I'm not sure how to do this, but I also like it maximized and undecorated, for which I use [devilspie](https://live.gnome.org/DevilsPie). Devil's pie allows me to run a system command using the window ID. So my specific question is:

- What system command sets the transparency of a window using the window ID in Mint/Cinnamon?

But I'd settle for another good way to get transparency in urxvt in Cinnamon.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the devilspie [manual](http://www.foosel.org/linux/devilspie), it can deal with transparency using the `-opacity` flag. Have you tried that?

### opacity

(opacity percent)

> boolean opacity(int percent)

Comment: The link is dead.